# How to remove default menu items for macOS app using SwiftUI and SwiftUI lifecycle?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

One can add a menu item using [`commands(content:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/windowgroup/commands(content:)), however, is there a way to remove the default menu items. In the case below, File, Edit, View, Window, and Help?

```
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
    }
    .commands {
        CommandMenu("TEST") {}
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: For now only via `NSApp.mainMenu`

Comment: Thanks, @Asperi ! Do you know where I can introduce this change with the SwiftUI lifecycle?